# Spring Batch Admin (2.0.0.M1): error creating bean batchMBeanExporter

Tags: spring, maven, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I am trying to run spring batch admin from spring boot application.

I am using [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-admin-samples) excellent example from Michael (@mminella). This application works fine.

However, I need similar application using maven; I went ahead and created one with same files, jobs, configs and dependencies. But I ended up in following exception.

Only difference I see is the version of spring-batch-core. With maven it's version is 3.0.6 while with gradle (Michael's application) has 3.0.4.

Not sure what's going on when I use maven; really appreciate your help. Please let me know if any additional details required.

Looking forward for your inputs.

Thank you,

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'batchMBeanExporter' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/Admin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/batch/spring-batch-admin-manager/2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-batch-admin-manager-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/META-INF/spring/batch/bootstrap/manager/jmx-context.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean#7807ac2c' of type [org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'jobService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean#7807ac2c': Post-processing of FactoryBean's object failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: @Scheduled method 'removeInactiveExecutions' found on bean target class 'SimpleJobService' but not found in any interface(s) for a dynamic proxy. Either pull the method up to a declared interface or switch to subclass (CGLIB) proxies by setting proxy-target-class/proxyTargetClass to 'true'.
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-batch-admin.version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring-batch-admin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-admin-manager</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-batch-admin.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-admin-domain</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-batch-admin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>sqljdbc4</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots-local</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot-local/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Spring Boot config

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {HypermediaAutoConfiguration.class, MultipartAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableBatchAdmin
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Finally, I was able to run the spring batch with spring batch admin; though with [this](https://github.com/vesperaba/spring-batch-admin-spring-boot) project.  Still not able to use @ EnableBatchAdmin with maven build.  Many thanks to mminella and @vesperaba.  Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid, [JobController](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-admin/pull/42) null pointer exception, put below

server.servletPath=/*

Best regards,
Jigar.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a way to make the annotation @EnableBatchAdmin in a maven project.

This allow you to fix the following error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'batchMBeanExporter' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/Admin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/batch/spring-batch-admin-manager/2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-batch-admin-manager-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/META-INF/spring/batch/bootstrap/manager/jmx-context.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean#7807ac2c' of type [org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'jobService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean#7807ac2c': Post-processing of FactoryBean's object failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: @Scheduled method 'removeInactiveExecutions' found on bean target class 'SimpleJobService' but not found in any interface(s) for a dynamic proxy. Either pull the method up to a declared interface or switch to subclass (CGLIB) proxies by setting proxy-target-class/proxyTargetClass to 'true'.
```

The solution was found in this issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-admin-samples/issues/12

and is to override the *jmx-context.xml* file by the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:mbean-server id="mbeanServer"/>

<context:mbean-export default-domain="spring.application" server="mbeanServer"/>

<!-- Override the `batchMBeanExporter` and set the `proxyTargetClass` property to true on the `jobService` proxy.
    This is a workaround for the related https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCHADM-126 -->
<bean id="batchMBeanExporter" class="org.springframework.batch.admin.jmx.BatchMBeanExporter">
    <property name="server" ref="mbeanServer"/>
    <property name="jobService">
        <bean class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
            <property name="targetName" value="jobService"/>
            <property name="proxyTargetClass" value="true"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultDomain" value="spring.application"/>
</bean>
```

by placing this code in your own *jmx.context.xml* file in main/resources/META-INF/spring/batch/override

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I was able to run the spring batch with spring batch admin; though with [this](https://github.com/vesperaba/spring-batch-admin-spring-boot) project.  Still not able to use @ EnableBatchAdmin with maven build.  Many thanks to mminella and @vesperaba.

Though I am facing another issue; when I run the project with 2.0.0.M1 from repository, it works fine. However, when I build project locally after resolving [JobController null pointer exception] (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-admin/pull/42);

1. I have to include "spring-batch-admin-resources" in POM explicitly;
   while this was not the case when I run the application using
   repository (libs-snapshot-local) 2.0.0.M1
   build.
2. When I include "spring-batch-admin-resources" application is not
   able to start saying that "cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1:
   '/job-configuration' is not a valid value for 'NCName'."

Any comments will be appreciated. Thank You.