# Spring Batch Project with Annotation Integrated with Spring Batch Admin

Tags: spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I have a Spring Batch Project which uses annotation based configurations and is a working code by itself. I now want to integrate this with a new Spring Batch Admin project. 
I tried some solutions available/answered in the blogs, like adding dependency of batch project to the batch admin project and modifying the META-INF/spring/batch/servlet/override/context-config.xml file to point to the batch project config file.
i.e. . The com.sample.springbatch.job package is present in the Spring Batch project.
However, I am not successful with the integration.

Can anybody point me to or suggest a solution where Spring Batch Project - Annotation Based is integrated with Spring Batch Admin project.

Thank you!
Sonali

Comment: found similar thread here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34615728/spring-batch-admin-2-0-0-m1-error-creating-bean-batchmbeanexporter

Comment: Hi Deepak, Thanks for pointing out to the link, but I think he was still not able to run batch admin with @EnableBatchProcessing, which is my core requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this with Batch Admin 2.0.0, you don't want to use @EnableBatchProcessing which is already provided with Spring Batch Admin rather you may use @EnableBatchAdmin. I've added the code in [github](https://github.com/dipack-v/batch-demo)

Comment: I would like to use the relase version of SBA which is 1.3.1 at the moment. Is there a way I can do it using 1.3.1 since in the documentation of SBA, it is mentioned that it can work with annotations but nowhere could I find how... very limited information which is not enough for implementation.